# How to create a loop that ignores hidden rows in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a simple process that loops through a sheet and send an email based on Name, Email, Subject, CC and Country as shown in the image.

[image]

The image is only showing row 5 and 10 but the macro is running all rows from 2 to 10 and generates 9 email drafts instead of 2 email drafts.

May I know how to only run the loop on existing rows in the sheet?

```vb
Sub send_mass_email()
Dim i As Integer
Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, place, business As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cel As Range

body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text

i = 2
'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1

Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
  
    name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0) 'extract first name
    email = Cells(i, 2).Value
    subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
    copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
    business = Cells(i, 5).Value
    place = Cells(i, 6).Value
    
    'replace place holders
    body = Replace(body, "C1", name)
    body = Replace(body, "C5", business)
    body = Replace(body, "C6", place)
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .to = email
        .cc = copy
        .subject = subject
        .body = body
        '.Attachments.Add ("") 'You can add files here
        .display
        '.Send
    End With
    
    'reset body text
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    i = i + 1
    
Loop

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
MsgBox "Email(s) Created!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try determining the last row on column A:A and then create a range of the visible cells: `Dim rng as Range` `set rng = Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` Then, iterate between `rng.Cells`...

Comment: `Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, place, business As String` declares 6 variants and 1 string.

Answer (score 1):

Add an IF THEN in your Loop to check if the row is hidden or not. If true, do nothing:

```
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

    If Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        'rest of your code
        '
        '
        '
        '
    End If

    i = i + 1
    
Loop
```

When filtering a range, those rows are hidden, so their property `Hidden` becomes True. If `False` it means those are the visible rows where you want to send email.